# How to debug a console application using CoreCLR in VS CODE?

Tags: visual-studio-code, coreclr

I have created a console application in VS CODE and configure CoreClr  to debug the code. I am able to see the output when i hit run. but debugger is not attached to breakpoints. Please suggest me to do the same. I will not use mono or node to debug.

Answer (score 1):

project.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "compilationOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true,
        "debugType": "portable"
    },

    "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library":"1.0.0-rc3-*" 
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "netstandardapp1.5": {
            "imports": "dnxcore50"
        }
    }
}
```

a newer installer:

[dotnet-win-x64.1.0.0.001661.exe](https://dotnetcli.blob.core.windows.net/dotnet/beta/Installers/1.0.0.001661/dotnet-win-x64.1.0.0.001661.exe)

full description:

[Instructions for setting up the .NET Core debugger - EXPERIMENTAL PREVIEW](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/blob/master/debugger.md)